# EF Reverse POCO generator not creating the automated return model when my SP has user defined table type as an input parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, poco, fmtonly

I am using EF reverse POCO generator. When I save the .tt file it automatically generates the return model of all the stored procedures.

In couple of my SP's, I have a user defined table type as one of the input params. For those SP's, my POCO is not creating the return models.
Earlier I had this issue for normal SP for which I used a return query from the temp tables. Adding **SET FMTONLY OFF** on top of the SP fixed that.

I am pretty sure it is with using the user defined table types that is causing the issue because when I just remove them, the return models are generated.
I am looking for a fix to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not raise an issue on CodePlex?

Comment: Use the latest version v2.17.2 which supports user defined types for stored procedures. Download here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838